# MVC3 RTM fails number type coercion when deserializing JSON

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-3

Simply put serializing data in the "application/json; charset=utf-8" format misbehaves in MVC3 (and possibly older versions). What happens is a nullable numbers all end up null, and numbers of "decimal" type end up 0 when serializing them inside a javascript object (to JSON) and leaving them as numbers and not strings.

**Here is the example code that illustrates this misbehavior**
*- - - this example was created using jquery-1.4.4.js and jquery.json-2.2.js - - - -*

*HomeController.cs:*

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.SaveUrl = Url.Action("Save", "Home", new { inspectionFormID = Guid.Empty }, Request.Url.Scheme);
        return View();
    }

    public JsonResult Save(Guid inspectionFormID, JsonTest result)
    {
        return Json(result);
    }

    public class JsonTest 
    {
        public double Double { get; set; }
        public double? DoubleNull { get; set; }

        public decimal Decimal { get; set; }
        public decimal? DecimalNull { get; set; }

        public Double Double2 { get; set; }
        public Double? Double2Null { get; set; }

        public Decimal Decimal2 { get; set; }
        public Decimal? Decimal2Null { get; set; }

        public Single Single { get; set; }
        public Single? SingleNull { get; set; }

        public float Float { get; set; }
        public float? FloatNull { get; set; }

        public int Int { get; set; }
        public int? IntNull { get; set; }

        public Int64 Int64 { get; set; }
        public Int64? Int64Null { get; set; }
    }

}
```

*Index.cshtml:*

```
    @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<b>@ViewBag.SaveUrl</b>
<br />
<hr />
<br />

<h3>Integral Numbers</h3>
<button type="button" class="a">Clicky</button>
<div></div>

<h3>Decimal Numbers (xx.0)</h3>
<button type="button" class="b">Clicky</button>
<div></div>

<h3>Decimal Numbers (xx.5)</h3>
<button type="button" class="c">Clicky</button>
<div></div>

<h3>Integral Numbers as strings</h3>
<button type="button" class="d">Clicky</button>
<div></div>

<h3>Decimal Numbers as strings (xx.5)</h3>
<button type="button" class="e">Clicky</button>
<div></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {
        var saveUrl = '@ViewBag.SaveUrl';

        var printObj = function (inObj, destx) {
            var dest = $('<table>').appendTo(destx),
                dst1 = $('<tr>').appendTo(dest),
                dst2 = $('<tr>').appendTo(dest);
            for (var p in inObj) {
                $('<th>', { text: p, css: { color: 'red', padding: '3px', background: '#dedede' } }).appendTo(dst1);
                $('<td>', { text: inObj[p] || 'null' }).appendTo(dst2);
            }
        };

        $('button.a').click(function () {
            var curr = $(this).next(),
                outR = {
                    Double: 12,
                    DoubleNull: 13,
                    Decimal: 14,
                    DecimalNull: 15,
                    Double2: 16,
                    Double2Null: 17,
                    Decimal2: 18,
                    Decimal2Null: 19,
                    Single: 20,
                    SingleNull: 21,
                    Float: 22,
                    FloatNull: 23,
                    Int: 24,
                    IntNull: 25,
                    Int64: 26,
                    Int64Null: 27
                };

            $('<hr />').appendTo(curr);
            printObj(outR, curr);

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: saveUrl,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: 'json',

                data: $.toJSON({
                    inspectionFormID: 'fbde6eda-dde6-4ba9-b82d-3a35349415f0',

                    result: outR
                }),

                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert('save failed');
                },

                success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    printObj(data, curr);
                }
            });
        });

        $('button.b').click(function () {
            var curr = $(this).next(),
                outR = {
                    Double: 12.0,
                    DoubleNull: 13.0,
                    Decimal: 14.0,
                    DecimalNull: 15.0,
                    Double2: 16.0,
                    Double2Null: 17.0,
                    Decimal2: 18.0,
                    Decimal2Null: 19.0,
                    Single: 20.0,
                    SingleNull: 21.0,
                    Float: 22.0,
                    FloatNull: 23.0,
                    Int: 24.0,
                    IntNull: 25.0,
                    Int64: 26.0,
                    Int64Null: 27.0
                };

            $('<hr />').appendTo(curr);
            printObj(outR, curr);

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: saveUrl,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: 'json',

                data: $.toJSON({
                    inspectionFormID: 'fbde6eda-dde6-4ba9-b82d-3a35349415f0',

                    result: outR
                }),

                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert('save failed');
                },

                success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    printObj(data, curr);
                }
            });
        });

        $('button.c').click(function () {
            var curr = $(this).next(),
                outR = {
                    Double: 12.5,
                    DoubleNull: 13.5,
                    Decimal: 14.5,
                    DecimalNull: 15.5,
                    Double2: 16.5,
                    Double2Null: 17.5,
                    Decimal2: 18.5,
                    Decimal2Null: 19.5,
                    Single: 20.5,
                    SingleNull: 21.5,
                    Float: 22.5,
                    FloatNull: 23.5,
                    Int: 24.5,
                    IntNull: 25.5,
                    Int64: 26.5,
                    Int64Null: 27.5
                };

            $('<hr />').appendTo(curr);
            printObj(outR, curr);

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: saveUrl,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: 'json',

                data: $.toJSON({
                    'inspectionFormID': 'fbde6eda-dde6-4ba9-b82d-3a35349415f0',

                    'result': outR
                }),

                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert('save failed');
                },

                success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    printObj(data, curr);
                }
            });
        });

        $('button.d').click(function () {
            var curr = $(this).next(),
                outR = {
                    Double:         '12',
                    DoubleNull:     '13',
                    Decimal:        '14',
                    DecimalNull:    '15',
                    Double2:        '16',
                    Double2Null:    '17',
                    Decimal2:       '18',
                    Decimal2Null:   '19',
                    Single:         '20',
                    SingleNull:     '21',
                    Float:          '22',
                    FloatNull:      '23',
                    Int:            '24',
                    IntNull:        '25',
                    Int64:          '26',
                    Int64Null:      '27'
                };

            $('<hr />').appendTo(curr);
            printObj(outR, curr);

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: saveUrl,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: 'json',
                data: $.toJSON({
                    'inspectionFormID': 'fbde6eda-dde6-4ba9-b82d-3a35349415f0',

                    'result': outR
                }),

                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert('save failed');
                },

                success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    printObj(data, curr);
                }
            });
    });

    $('button.e').click(function () {
        var curr = $(this).next(),
                outR = {
                    Double:         '12.5',
                    DoubleNull:     '13.5',
                    Decimal:        '14.5',
                    DecimalNull:    '15.5',
                    Double2:        '16.5',
                    Double2Null:    '17.5',
                    Decimal2:       '18.5',
                    Decimal2Null:   '19.5',
                    Single:         '20.5',
                    SingleNull:     '21.5',
                    Float:          '22.5',
                    FloatNull:      '23.5',
                    Int:            '24.5',
                    IntNull:        '25.5',
                    Int64:          '26.5',
                    Int64Null:      '27.5'
                };

        $('<hr />').appendTo(curr);
        printObj(outR, curr);

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: saveUrl,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: $.toJSON({
                'inspectionFormID': 'fbde6eda-dde6-4ba9-b82d-3a35349415f0',

                'result': outR
            }),

            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('save failed');
            },

            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                printObj(data, curr);
            }
        });
});
    });

</script>
```

Run it click each button once, and look at the before/after. Thanks in advance for any insight, correction or help that you can provide to resolve this issue.

you can also download the code samples listed above and see the official bug report for this at this link: http://aspnet.codeplex.com/workitem/8114

---

**EDIT: I am including this image to help everyone get what's going on here**

[click here to see the screenshot of the included example running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1Zno.png)

Basically: { propertyThatIsADecimal: 54 } becomes { propertyThatIsADecimal: 0 } on the server for multiple different number types in varying scenarios which there doesn't seem to be any rhyme or reason to.

Comment: Well 2 parts I suppose, looking for a suitable non-hack fix and inquiring as to whether or not this is expected behavior (from someone who is an MVC pro)

Comment: a custom JSON serializer looks to be the best workaround at the moment, this issue is not important (low) on the MVC bug tracker -_-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is because when MVC encounters a number it treats it as an `Int32`. As such there are no converters, for some reason, from `Int32` to say a `Decimal` or a `Nullable<Int64>`. There are a couple ways around this issue. Strings, as you already have in your project or to create a custom model binder.

```
public class JsonTestModelBinder : IModelBinder {
    public virtual object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) {
        JsonTest result = new JsonTest();

        foreach (var property in typeof(JsonTest).GetProperties()) {
            //the value provider starts with the name of the property we're binding to
            //i'm not sure if this changed or not as i don't recall having to do this
            //before - you can remove "result." if your needs don't require it
            var value = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("result." + property.Name);
            if (value != null && value.RawValue != null) {
                //are we binding to a nullable?
                if (property.PropertyType.IsGenericType && property.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition().Equals(typeof(Nullable<>))) {
                    property.SetValue(result, Convert.ChangeType(value.AttemptedValue, new NullableConverter(property.PropertyType).UnderlyingType), null);
                } else {
                    property.SetValue(result, Convert.ChangeType(value.AttemptedValue, property.PropertyType), null);
                }
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

I'm not entirely sure why we still can't convert from `Int32` to `Decimal` but the problem exists within MVC's `ValueProviderResult.ConvertSimpleType`. It's using `TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(your propertyType)` and there's no conversions available for those types.

I don't like this particular method but it's the only one available to you for now.

Comment: Sounds to me like someone got lazy and piggybacked convert or something, I really hope this gets repaired at some point because it is my personal favorite way to do asynchronous communication and also the way MS Ajax for web forms worked by default... The more manual ways of doing it aren't a deal breaker but it seems kind of hacky. Anyway thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I **only** glanced at your question, so I apologize if this doesn't apply. But I remember encountering a few issues with Json:

1. Was this a binding issue? If so, maybe you can implement a custom binding. (Apparently MVC3 uses the JsonFactory already).
2. I can't remember the issue, but I needed to add JsonRequestBehaviour.AllowGet when making jQuery calls using .getJSON.
3. Does it matter that you don't have a [HttpGet] or [HttpPost] on your Save method?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but unfortunately no, none of this seems to be applicable. Somewhere in the MVC stack the JSON is either not being treated as JSON or it is being treated like JSON and the resulting deserialization to Dictionary<string, object> is not being coerced correctly during the mapping to the concrete object when moving between number types (e.g. int to decimal) but oddly enough (as my example illustrates) the coercion on string to decimal or other works as expected. It's just a bummer and a hack to force your javascript to transform numbers to strings prior to serialization.

Comment: I downloaded your code and ran the example and it was not clear to me from your description what the "before and after" was supposed to be. Can you distill this down to a single example? I'm assuming that if we can figure it out for that case, then we can figure it out for the rest.

Comment: as for the error, you need both: jquery-1.4.4.js and jquery.json-2.2.js  (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.js AND http://jquery-json.googlecode.com/files/jquery.json-2.2.js). And the simplest case would be, "data: $.toJSON({ param: { val: 5 } })" and "data: $.toJSON({ param: { val: 5.5 } })" where the receiving action signature looks like:  public JsonResult Save(simpleExample param)  and the simpleExample object looks like:   public class simpleExample { public decimal val {get;set;} }

Comment: Oh and, before: "before being sent up to the server" & after: "on the server/ in the return" (since the action returns what was sent up, and there is no problem from server -> client, just client -> server), thanks for your time. The example displays the before and then the after on return.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded your code and ran the example. When I clicked the button I received a JavaScript error (Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method) at:

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: saveUrl,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: 'json',

            data: $.toJSON({
                inspectionFormID: 'fbde6eda-dde6-4ba9-b82d-3a35349415f0',

                result: outR
            }),

            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('save failed');
            },

            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                printObj(data, curr);
            }
        });
```

It was also not clear to me from your description what the "before/after" was supposed to be. Can you distill this down to the absolute simplest case with just a single example? I'm assuming that if we can figure it out for that case, then it will apply to the rest.

Comment: as for the error, you need both: jquery-1.4.4.js and jquery.json-2.2.js (ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.js AND jquery-json.googlecode.com/files/jquery.json-2.2.js). **And the simplest case would be,** `data: $.toJSON({ param: { val: 5 } })
`
**and** `data: $.toJSON({ param: { val: 5.5 } })

` **where the receiving action signature looks like:** `
public JsonResult Save(simpleExample param)

` **and the simpleExample object looks like:** `public class simpleExample {
   public decimal val { get; set; }
}`

Comment: Oh and, before: "before being sent up to the server" & after: "on the server/ in the return" (since the action returns what was sent up, and there is no problem from server -> client, just client -> server), thanks for your time. The example displays the before and then the after on return.